# How do I allow mysql client connections to be established with our mysql web server?

Tags: mysql

It seems that the web server is preventing me to change permissions to the user. It does not allow me to GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; and returns an error message of access denied for the username that I'm using.

It also appears that the folder etc in the file manager is empty whereas in the given link below, it shows that the bind address can be edited in the my.cnf inside etc folder.

How do I allow my mysql database to be accessible remotely by any computer?
[image]

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Which user are you using to connect? Can you select/modify data with that user? Can you show the results of "select user,host from mysql.user;"?

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in a `root` or another user with the ability to grant permissions?

Comment: What is the result of `show grants;` for your user? You need the privelege `GRANT OPTION`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/grant.html

Answer (score 0):

The `bind` option in `my.cnf` is not that problem (since you can connect, the MySQL server is just not letting you in), and judging from the screenshot, you don't seem to have the permissions to edit that file anyways.

Most likely, your request is not coming from `202.54.10.20`, or you have mistyped username/password. If the web application runs on the same machine as the MySQL server, connections will come from somewhere in the 127.0.0.0/8 range.

Look at the connection string in your web application:

- If it is a public IP address, check username/password and originating IP.
- If it starts with `127.`, GRANT to your local address.
- If it is `localhost`, you're connecting via Unix socket instead of TCP. This is a good thing, and you can simply GRANT to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

To issue this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

You MUST connect to the database first. So if you don't have permissions to remotely access database, you should go to the database server host and login locally, using root@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that there is an option which basically do the same thing as what I wanted it to be doing. There is an option for the user to enable remote database access to its clients. 
[image]